# WiFi “Network Notification” greyed out

Tags: wi-fi, settings

I have a Sony Xperia Z1 Compact running Android 4.4.4 KitKat.

I am unable to un-check "Network Notification" under `Settings` -> `Wi-Fi` -> `Advanced` as its greyed out. Is there a way of un-checking that box?

[image: Screenshot of Advance Wi-Fi settings]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Comment: Did you turn on WIFI ?

Comment: Yeah the problem was wifi was off but as Chirag64 pointed out there's no reason it should be on... Anyway turning the Wfi on before trying to uncheck works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable your Wi-Fi for that option to be available for checking or unchecking. Seems like a bug since I don't see any reason why the Wi-Fi should be enabled for the option to be available for toggle.